# How to select between two varchar columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to select some rows between to values in SQL Server, but it not working.

In the past I made something like this in Oracle.

This is my code

```
  Select * 
  From TABLENAME 
  Where CU_CODE Between 'ELCTRN/6601' and 'ELCTRN/6699'
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: *"but it not working"* >> Please clarify. You mean to say no rows are selected? You are getting an error of some sort?

Comment: yes I mean no rows are selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach... Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (CU_CODE  NVARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
  (N'ELCTRN/6601')
, (N'ELCTRN/6602')
, (N'ELCTRN/6603')
, (N'ELCTRN/6604')
, (N'ELCTRN/6605')
, (N'ELCTRN/6606')
, (N'ELCTRN/6607');

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS tbl
WHERE tbl.CU_CODE BETWEEN N'ELCTRN/6603' AND N'ELCTRN/6605'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Select  * 
From TABLENAME 
WHERE   CAST(RIGHT(CU_CODE,4) AS INT) Between 6601 and 6699
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (CU_CODE  NVARCHAR(50));

    INSERT INTO @T  
    VALUES('ELCTRN/6601'),
    ('ELCTRN/6602'),
    ('ELCTRN/6603'),
    ('ELCTRN/6605'),
    ('ELCTRN/668'),
    ('ELCTRN/661'),
    ('ELCTRN/662') ;

    SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT CU_CODE,SUBSTRING(CU_CODE, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CU_CODE),       LEN(CU_CODE)) AS CODE FROM @T
    ) AS T 
    WHERE CODE BETWEEN 6601 AND 6603
```